# What does the tab key do in Foxit?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, foxit-reader

Whenever I bump tab, the view seems to jump an arbitrary number of pages down. I can't figure out exactly what this behavior is, but as it's easy for foxit to register tab when you're alt-tabbing about, it's rather annoying. (I've tried to locate it in settings as well as google with no luck)

In addition to 'what is it?', is there either a way to turn it off or to jump backwards to what you were reading before bumping tab?

[Foxit Reader Version 6.0.3.0524, although I speculate that this generalizes a bit]

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is used to advance the cursor to the next tab stop.

*Is there either a way to turn it off or to jump backwards to what you were reading before bumping tab?*

Try:

Right-click the toolbar region -> Customize Toolbar -> choose the Keyboard tab -> choose the View menu -> change the shortcuts for *Next Page* and *Previous Page*.

See the [shortcuts available in foxit](http://kbmode.com/windows/foxit-reader-6-keyboard-shortcuts/).

Comment: "Next Page" and "Previous Page" go forward and backwards by a page (they're just the arrow keys, part of standard reading) and don't seem related. Nothing in that menu mentions tab. Also, your link doesn't mention the Tab key or 'tab stops'. Any other ideas on how to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If your document has form fields or comments in it, Tab might be advancing to the next form field or comment. In both cases, the way "next" is defined might be causing your view to jump around (by default it's the order the fields/comments were added).